# Classification techniques for continuous arrays as inputs and scalar categorical variable as output

Tags: classification, machine-learning-model

a newbie here. If you had any ideas about the following, that would be great.
Suppose for a given data set:
T’s and Y’s are arrays with
T = [0 1 2 3 5 6 7]
Y= [4 7 9 3 6 1]
So at T=0, Y=4 and so on
Z = [Red] with just one element in Z.
T and Y are continuous inputs.
Z discrete (can be either red or yellow).

Another given set:
T = [1 3 4 9 3]
Y= [4 9 2 1 6]
Z=[Yellow]

Suppose I  have many similar sets, what classification techniques can I use to explore relations which take T and Y as array inputs and outputs Z of single element?

Comment: Would https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression work?